# How do I escape Unicode backspace chars. in Java for a tomcat log

Tags: java, linux, web-applications, tomcat, unicode

Could someone please explain what is the best way to escape any unwanted unicode characters (i.e. backspace) in a Java Web App?

I am using a java web app and this is for the tomcat log generated from the app. I'm asking for the purpose that any backspaces do not actually backspace the log when viewing it. I'm also interested in a more complete solution than simply taking out backspaces through a simple regex.

I've looked at StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() but this is not StringEscapeUtils.escapeLinux() obviously. 
I've also looked at going through the bytes. and using other packages (which i'm sorry but forgot about and discarded them)

StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons is the only solution so far I've had half-working for me. Is there a better way? One that will include other unicode characters that way find there way into my app?

FYI: I am receiving these unicode characters through a GET request.

Comment: This has become a replacement problem I believe. Taking out all the characters that would screw up a standard log file viewing session using vim in GNU/Linux. These chars don't actually rewrite the log as I had originally thought!

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing that you wish to search for some literal that may include backslashes. If thats the case use Pattern.quote(String).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't solve my backspacing problems. and it adds \Q and \E so I'm thinking any \b in the linux terminal window or log will consumed even if it is not erasing the log file. it is actually stored in the file as a backspace. Maybe i'll have to specifically remove these of convert them to a codepoint representation which doesn't translate in the console.

Comment: Why not filter the unwanted yourself..loop over the source string characters and only copy the chars your interested to a StringBuilder.

Comment: because i want to see if someone is trying to inject any other characters